# How to print variable from subroutine

Tags: python

In my code below, I don't know why when the output `total_cost` is zero, and why the subroutine doesn't change that variable. Also are the parameters of my subroutine wrong, like should I add them outside the subroutine and then use those defined variables or something?

```
total_cost = 0
from datetime import date
def valid_integer():
 not_valid = True
 while not_valid:
   try:
     number = int(input())
     not_valid = False
   except ValueError:
     print("You must enter a whole number")
 return number
print("Welcome to Copington Adventure them park!")
print(
"\n""These are our ticket prices:"
"\n""Adult ticket over  16's  £20 "
"\n""Child ticket under 16's  £12  "
"\n""Senior ticket over 60's  £11"  )

print("How many adult tickets do you want?")
adult = int(input())
print("How many child tickets do you want?")
child = int(input())
print("How many Senior tickets do you want?")
senior = int(input())
print("Your total ticket price is:")
print(total_cost)
def entrance(child_total, adult_total, senior_total):
  total_child = child * 12
  total_senior = senior * 11
  total_adult = adult * 20
  total_cost = total_child + total_senior + total_adult
  return total_cost
  print(total_cost)
```

Comment: Go read the chapter in your textbook on functions again. `return` followed by `print` indicates to me (and probably to your teacher as well) that you fundamentally misunderstand what functions *do*. "Putting code in a function" doesn't mean "indent it and add a `def` to the top". It's a substantive change and requires understanding of the relevant programming concepts to do correctly.

Comment: Your functions are defined, but not called. You don't use the parameter inside the entrance function. You should review functions in a python tutorial

Answer (score 0):

`return` exits the function, so any code after a return will not execute. Swap the order of these two lines:

```
  return total_cost
  print(total_cost)
```

The required reading on this is "scope". Code in a function has access to the variables in its own scope, and it has access to its parent scope, which is the file it was defined in. After a function call completes, the scope, and all variables created in it that aren't returned or stashed in a higher scope, tend to be destroyed.

Returned variables are passed back to the caller's scope. So the lifecycle is something like this:

```
def myfunction(a, b):
    a = a * 2
    print(a) #this will evaluate later when we call the function
    b = a + b
    return b

c = myfunction(1, 2)  # jumps to the first line of the function with a=1 and b=2
# the function evaluates, which prints "2" and returns 4.
# The label "c" is then created in the outer scope, and 4 is assigned to it. So now c = 4

print(a)  # this is an error, a is not part of this outer scope
print(b)  # this is an error, b is not part of this outer scope
print(c)  # outputs 4
print(myfunction(1, 2))  # what do you think this outputs?
```